# Error in uploading sketch to digispark attiny85 board

Tags: attiny85, digispark

I'm trying to use Digispark attiny85 board and running into issues uploading the sketch.

The drivers are correctly installed. I have followed [this page](https://www.electronicshub.org/getting-started-with-attiny85/) as a reference.

Below the sketch and the error message.

[image]

Thanks for any help

Comment: "LAB C Student 8" is part of your installation and work path. It contains spaces. I can not see the flasher call (launcher) complete but it seems as the path is not quoted in "..." so the complete path is separated in many arguments and thus the flasher can not find the hex file to upload. It's just a guess. But the tool calls in the output above do not fail and the paths are escaped therein.

Comment: please remove the picture of text and replace it with the actual text ... some of us are unable to view images ... it is also easier to test your code

Comment: You cant have spaces in your name. I made a second account named 'test' to run the code